# nservicebus: What latency/performance I should be expecting?

Tags: structuremap, nservicebus

There is a delay between bus.send and the handler picking it up.

2 second delay with default config.
3 second delay with structuremap used for the builder.

Is this normal?
Can I expect the speeds to be significantly faster in a production environment on servers?

Method:

- The solution I'm using is built with the code first example that pops up when you pull down NSB from nuget.
- I'm testing by adding a UTCNow to the message at the Bus.Send and then appending another UTCNow at the handler.
- I'm running the tests on a Windows 8 i7-3517U @ 1.90Ghz 2.40 Ghz with 8GB of Ram, not sure about the disk speed. Dell Laptop.
- At the time of the tests the CPU is running 5-10% with 4GB of free ram.

Comment: is that for the first message? what about following messages, they should be quick?

Comment: @AndreasÖhlund You were right, do you want to put in an answer so I can mark it? Maybe an explanation on why it takes awhile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andreas Öhlund responded in a comment to the OP: "is that for the first message? what about following messages, they should be quick?".

Turns out every message after that was near instant, so it looks like it just takes awhile for the process to start. I encountered a similar issue with Mass Transit. However, if you try to send a message right after starting with MT, then nothing looks like it happens at all. Apparently MSMQ needs a warmup period.